# Why was queen Victoria upset when she found out that Abdul was married?

Tags: character, victoria-and-abdul

The movie "[Victoria and Abdul](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5816682/)" shows the history of a unique friendship between the most powerful queen of the British Empire and a lowly Muslim servant from India.

At one stage, Abdul tells Victoria that "she is the most special person in his life, even more than his wife":

> **Abdul:** When I first came to England, I was terrified of you. But you're a very kind lady. You're a very unique lady to me.
>
> **Victoria:** And you are very,
>   very unique to me, Abdul.
>
> **Abdul:** I know that you are much older than me, and you are the Queen of England, and the Empress of India, and I'm just a humble munshi. But I think
>   you are the most special person in my whole life. Even more special
>   than my wife.
>
> **Victoria:** Wife?
>
> **Abdul:** Yes.
>
> **Victoria:** You're married?
>
> **Abdul:** Of course.
>
> **Victoria:** Where is your wife?
>
> **Abdul:** In India.
>
> **Victoria:** why didn't you tell me
>   you were married ?
>
> **Abdul:** I didn't think it mattered.
>
> **Victoria: Well, of course it matters. It changes everything.** You must return to India immediately. And bring her back at once.

Later on, Victoria brings it back again, saying that Abdul really hurt her by not mentioning his wife:

> **Victoria:** I promoted you in the face
>   of considerable opposition
>   and disquiet
>   from the Household.
>   **I even turned
>   a blind eye
>   when you failed to tell me
>   that you were married,**
>   which, as you know,
>   came as quite a surprise.

Why is she so upset about it? Was it because she had some romantic feelings towards him? Seems unlikely, judging by her age (around 80 at this stage) and the fact that she still deeply loves her dead husband Albert.

Answer (score 9):

Now admittedly, I haven't seen this film. But judging from this bit:

> You must return to India immediately. And bring her back at once.

It sounds like she's upset not because Abdul is married, but because he had to leave his wife behind in India. So she's telling him to go fetch his wife and bring her to England so they can be together again.

Wikipedia's plot summary seems to confirm this interpretation:

> When Victoria discovers he is married, she invites his wife and mother-in-law to join him to England.

No mention of her being upset at all, merely that she has his relatives join him in England.

Comment: Hmm, possible, but later she mentions that she has been hurt by Abdul for not mentioning his wife. The whole situation could be read as if Victoria was flirting with Abdul and then got disappointed when found that he is unavailable, but if course it would be bit ridiculous.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with F1Krazy's answer. However, that explains the first interaction ("Well, of course it matters. It changes everything. You must return to India immediately. And bring her back at once"). Later in the movie, the queen is reacting differently.

Later, she says, "I even turned a blind eye when you failed to tell me that you were married." She is saying that royal subjects do not keep secrets from the Queen. They do not leave out important details about their lives, such as this detail. It is a sign of disrespect towards the Queen, especially since she and Abdul have developed such an intimate friendship. She "turned a blind eye" because many might have interpreted Abdul's omission as an insult to the monarchy.